# Classification of subgroups of finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, finite-groups

For me the relevant number of subgroups of a finite group is the number of non-isomorphic subgroups. Mathematicians seems to have an other opinion.

There is a related classification called automorphic subgroups, when there is an automorphism on the main group that maps a subgroup on a subgroup, which seems to be a stronger condition. A weaker condition than automorphic subgroups is [conjugate subgroups](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_subgroups).

> What is the relation between conjugate subgroups and isomorphic
>   subgroups?
>
> Why isn't isomorphic subgroups more interesting in
>     mathematics?

Comment: Conjugate subgroup are isomorphic. I don't think more can really be said. Not sure why you think they are not more interesting. It all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: is that so? I have never seen it pointed out or beeing proved and on http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page the three concepts seems to be separate.

Comment: That conjugate subgroups are isomorphic is pretty straightforward. Conjugation is an automorphism, so it restricts to isomorphisms on subgroups. Could you point to a more specific point where they are treated as separate?

Comment: If you are looking specifically at the *number* of subgroups, then isomorphism is a good equivalence relation. But within a group $G$ group theoreticians want to know more, for instance how $G$ acts on its subgroups. This yields insights in the intrinsic structure of the group in question. So basically you are then considering $Aut(G)$ as a group acting on $G$. Talking about conjugation, the inner automorphisms, $Inn(G)$ form a (normal) subgroup of $Aut(G)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, no I'm just trying to classify subgroups on my implementation of sets http://forthmath.blogspot.se but was confused not finding anything about isomorphic subgroups.

Comment: @NickyHekster: I guess I had to study group actions, that wasn't actual 45 years ago on my university when I studied grouptheory.

Comment: @Lehs, fair enough - and yes do study group actions, which is a very powerful concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give you the following example:

Let $G$ be a group with a non-trivial homomorphism $G \to Aut(G)$, for instance $G=S_3$.

Then we have the semi-direct product (which is not a direct product) $G \rtimes G$.

The two factors give rise to two isomorphic subgroups $G \times e$ and $e \times G$. But one of them is a normal subgroup and one of them is not, so they clearly should be distinguished when classifiying subgroups of $G \rtimes G$, shouldn't they?

This should give you an idea, why it is not enough to consider only isomorphic subgroups.

Comment: Yes, thanks! My purpose is to define the relation 'isomorphic' on my very limited implementation of groups, as subgroups of $S_6$ or something. So isomorphism is quite enough for me.